# IIS, Python and reading files in a directory

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, iis, google-visualization

i've setup IIS to run Python scripts using the instructions found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494.
I've confirmed that it works.

I then tried this example using google charts along with a python script to return the data: http://www.jansipke.nl/using-google-visualization-api-with-own-data-source/
That too works fine as well.

However, when i modify the python script to read a local file, i get a DataTable with no rows.
If i run the python script directly in the browser it prints a json object that looks like this:

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse(
{
   reqId:'0',
   status:'ok',
   table:
   {
      cols:
      [
         {id:'Date',label:'',type:'string'},
         {id:'Price',label:'',type:'number'}
      ],
      rows:
      [
      ]
   }
});
```

If however i run the script on the command line, it does print a json object with many rows.
I suspect the issue is accessing local files from a script being run in the browser.  I am not sure how to solve this however, esp in context of IIS.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:  After some further investigation i found that the pythone.exe is receiving a ACCESS DENIED error when trying to access the path as user NT AUTHORITY\IUSR.  I can not add IUSR to the networked path.  So i'm exploring if maybe i can run as myself, since i know i have read access to that networked directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue i did three things (not sure if all are required):
1. Create a new Application Pool and set Identiy to custom, using a login that has access to the networked paths.
2. For my virtual directories and applications, use the above application pool. 
3. In advanced settings for my virtual director and application, i set physical path credentials to a specific user that has access to the networked path.